# Run node express in docker with mounted volume

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to mount a volume in docker container. basically want to run node for development purpose. but I cant see files copied over there. For now not running node just to debug things. I want to see first the volume files to be copied on container.

Tried everything but with no result.

Seeing two directory created out of nowhere in 'node' folder. those directory names are 'app' and 'src'

**DockerBuild**

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /node/
#COPY ./package.json ./package.json

# RUN npm install

COPY . ./node

EXPOSE 3000

# CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]

RUN ["apt-get", "update"]
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "nano"]

CMD [ "npm", "run" , "start" ]
#CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

**DockerCompse**

```
version: '3.8'  #specifies docker compose version
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /var/www/node/dram/:/node/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      DEBUG: nodejs-docker-express:*
```

**FileStrcuture**

[image]

Comment: Can you just run Node, without Docker?  Your image doesn't really seem to do anything – its main command is a meaningless `tail` and you hide all of its content with a volume mount – what benefit are you hoping to get from using a container rather than host tools here?

Comment: @DavidMaze There is no issue to run node. Even Node with Docker is working fine. I wanted to have a mounted volume from host to use as src of code. Mounted volume seems to be empty if go inside the container. "tail" I have used it to have the container running without running node. So I can exec it and inspect the directories. making and edit to avoid confusion.

Comment: @DavidMaze basically I want to run node/express from mounted volume. So if I change source code we don't need to build again. mounted volume will point to host's directory of source code.